# how to print every fifth row in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with numbers

```
20
18
21
16
14
30
40
24
```

and I need to output four files with rows printed with intervals of 4
So we have rows 1,5,9...

```
20
14
```

Then rows 2,6,10...

```
18
30
```

Then 3,7,11...

```
21
40
```

and then 4,8,12...

```
16 
24
```

I did try the code below but it does not give me the control over the starting row

```
awk 'NR % 4 == 0'
```

Answer (score 3):

In a single awk you can do:

```
awk '{print > ("file" (NR%4))}' inputfile
```

This will send the output to files `file0`, `file1`, `file2` and `file3`

Answer (score 1):

You may use these `awk` commands:

```
awk -v n=1 'NR%4 == n%4' file
20
14

awk -v n=2 'NR%4 == n%4' file
18
30

awk -v n=3 'NR%4 == n%4' file
21
40

awk -v n=4 'NR%4 == n%4' file
16
24
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO `awk` is the best solution. You can use `sed`:
Inputfile generated with `seq 12`:

```
for ((i=1;i<5; i++)); do 
   sed -n $i~4w$i.out <(seq 12)
done
```

Here `w$i.out` writes to file $i.out.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ne '1~4w file1' -e '2~4w file2' -e '3~4w file3' -e '4~4w file4' file
```